# Multisite Create New Blog Plugin

Tags: multisite

Looking for a plugin that displays a form for visitors to create a new blog on a network, where they can answer a few basic questions on a form along with some admin options for me to tweak.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably needing a membership type plugin. I've used the following before and it works great for creating a blog community.

http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership